# Mobile Connect STOP keyword

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

I would like to understand better the STOP keyword functionality in the Mobile Connect Feature when I subscriber sends an SMS with this keyword inside.
What field and system table will be updated (e.g. Mobile Connect Demographics, Mobile Connect Subscriptions) ?
Could I export the unsubscribed contacts for each keyword in a csv file?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the query we are using to retrieve most recent unsubscribes from our MobileConnect

```
SELECT 
a._MobileNumber AS MobileNumber, 
a._MobileSubscriptionID AS MobileSubscriptionID, 
a._OptOutDate AS OptOutDate,
b.EmailAddress,
b.Contact_Key AS ContactKey
FROM _MobileSubscription a
JOIN Contacts b ON a._MobileNumber = b.PhoneNumber
JOIN Permissions c ON b.Contact_Key = c.Contact_Key
WHERE _OptOutStatusID = 1
AND c.PermissionSMS = 'TRUE'
AND DateDiff(day,PermissionSMSJoinDate,_OptOutDate) > 0
```

I hope this will lead you in the right direction.

All the fields in `_MobileSubscription` can be seen here:

```
SELECT 
_CreatedBy AS CreatedBy,
_OptOutMethodID AS OptOutMethodID,
_MobileNumber AS MobileNumber,
_OptInDate AS OptInDate,
_Source AS Source,
_OptOutStatusID AS OptOutStatusID,
_OptOutDate AS OptOutDate,
_ModifiedBy AS ModifiedBy,
_SourceObjectId AS SourceObjectId,
_SubscriptionDefinitionID AS SubscriptionDefinitionID,
_CreatedDate AS CreatedDate,
_OptInStatusID AS OptInStatusID,
_OptInMethodID AS OptInMethodID,
_ModifiedDate AS ModifiedDate
FROM _MobileSubscription
```

Comment: Hi @Lukas L, i followed your suggestion and i retrieved many records into the data extension, but i would like to extract other information (e.g. keyword, OptOutMethod). Do you have the correct field name used in the _MobileSubscription system table? And have you created another query using Mobile Demographic because the system gave back the error message "_MobileDemographic is not a known data extension or system data view." ?

Comment: Hi robertoc - I have added the full list of fields to my answer.  `OptOutMethodID` is there too

Comment: Thank you very much @Lukas L. do you have also the fields of Mobile Demographics?

Comment: No, sorry @robertoc - this I haven't

Comment: Thanks for this useful insight - it has really helped me. Does anyone know what each of the possible values mean for OptOutMethodID OptOutStatusID The results of my query return an numeric value - it would be really useful to have some documentation as to what these values mean.

Comment: Remember to mark the answer as accepted, @cmbob