# Extract Data from Mobile Connect

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

Can i create a query in order to extract records from MobileConnect Subscriptions and MobileConnect Demographics?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there this is the only queryable data view currently for Mobile Connect:

https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_undeliverable_sms/

source: SFMC help documentation

Comment: You can also see the answer of this case "Mobile Connect STOP keyword" http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/150644/mobile-connect-stop-keyword/150679?noredirect=1#comment220416_150679