# Extract mobile connect list of unsubscribes

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, automationstudio, data-extract, tracking-extract

I have tried to find information about how to automate the export of MobileConnect status for unsubscribes with stop-code.

I've found [this](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/data_views/data_view_subscribersms/) official documentation about querying data views as suggested in [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/150653/extract-data-from-mobile-connect) thread here on stackexchange. But according to the documentation that query does not work with mobile connect.

[This](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/150644/mobile-connect-stop-keyword/150679?noredirect=1#comment220416_150679) thread gave me some tips on a possible query but cant this be done as similar to a "Tracking extract activity" where no SOQL knowledge is necessary? Can someone point me in the right direction of where to look for a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the closest thing you can get to something like a Tracking Extract Activity would be to schedule a "SMS Message Detail Report" from within Analytics Builder and schedule it to save the file to the Enhanced FTP.

The resulting CSV report gives detail of every Mobile Originated and Mobile Terminated message that's gone through MobileConnect in the selected time range. This is overkill as you'll get STOP requests mixed in with everything else, but they're very easy to filter and no SQL required (SOQL is a Sales Cloud thing).

Comment: Thanks! As you said, a lot of other information in the report but with the filtering it gets the job done.